# how can use loop or IF in case when statements in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

```
select distinct
  x.vrgid, x.Weights, x.geom
from
  (select
     -- postcodes.id as postcodeid ,,fishnet.geom as geom
     fishnet.gid  as vrgid,
     fishnet.geom as geom,

     CASE WHEN
       st_intersects(centroids.geom, urban.geom) and counts.nonurbancells != 0
       THEN 0.95 :: numeric / counts.urbancells -------1st case
     WHEN st_intersects(centroids.geom, urban.geom) and counts.nonurbancells = 0
       THEN 1.00 :: numeric / counts.urbancells ---2ndcase
     WHEN Not st_intersects(centroids.geom, urban.geom) = fishnet.gid :: boolean and counts.nonurbancells != 0
       THEN 0.05 :: numeric / counts.nonurbancells ----3rd case
     ELSE 0
     END          AS Weights
   from vrg.urban_nonurban_count_new as counts 
     inner join vrg.gfk_2016_id_5_digit_pcd_areas2013_projected as postcodes on postcodes.id = counts.postid
     right outer join vrg.rdsid_86_quadgrid_centroids as centroids on st_contains(postcodes.geom, centroids.geom)
     left outer join vrg.rdsid86_quadgrid AS fishnet on fishnet.gid = centroids.gid
     right outer join vrg.rdsid86_katrisk_poly_projected as urban on st_intersects(urban.geom, fishnet.geom)
   where postcodes.id = '42395') as x
```

I have several case statements in my PL/Pgsql function in which the I get duplicate rows (with duplicate vrgids). Below is the query result

[image]

Here (the marked row) with id 7192 is the result of 1st case statement(refer the query)
What I would like to do is use loop or if condition to remove the vrgid and corresponding weights from the result once the 1st case statement is true.
So thet I won't get duplicate records. How is it possible?

May be I should use a condition in 3rd statement to result out the vrgids not present in 1st case statement.

Comment: ju can just `distinct on ` to have only first row...

Comment: I'm not sure if first row will always be result of first case condition. Maybe more reliable would be to return composite type or json value that would have both weights and case number.